# Friend functions not locating private members

Tags: c++

Please do not vote this down or mark this question as a duplicate for all of the answers that I have seen in other questions have not worked for me.

I created a class called contact that stores information about contacts.  I was trying to implement an operator<< to output all information, so I had to make it a friend function.  The problem with this is that I am unable to access any of the class's member functions.  My code is as follows:

contact.h:

```
class contact {
    long id;
    string first;
    string middle;
    string last;
    string company;
    string home;
    string office;
    string email;
    string mobile;
    string street;
    string city;
    string state;
    long zip;
    string country;
    vector<contact> affiliates;
public:
    // output and input
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const contact &);
};
```

contact.cpp:

```
...
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, contact &rec) {
    print(os, rec.id);

    return os;
}
...
```

As you see, the function prototype is exactly the same, and I am not enclosing the class inside a namespace, which leaves no reason for the operator to be unable to access a member variable.  Is this a problem with my prototype?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh um.. @Anton Savin already answered my question.  Thanks anyway though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator<<` declaration and definition are actually *not* the same. In the `friend` declaration the second parameter is `const contact &`, and in the definition it's just `contact&`.

So the definition is actually unrelated to a `friend` declaration in the class, and defines another function which is not a friend of `contact`.

Comment: Oh my.. I didn't even realize I did that.  Cheers to you :D